# Post processing method to make alpha mask of an image better in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a background removal model for images containing human. Which post-processing methods can I apply to erase unwanted noisy white areas from the produced alpha mask, as can be seen from the image?

[sample image.](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/32217414/201177558-8ff46192-e5a3-4c6c-ac18-39f26f543016.jpeg) I want to remove noisy-cloudy area between sharp edges

I tried basic opencv operations like erosion-dilation but they did not seem to help.

Comment: Similar working project: [rembg](https://pypi.org/project/rembg/)

Comment: I am not looking for pretrained models, I am training my own model. None of pretrained models are sufficient for my case @Markus

Comment: Please share information on what you have already tried and where you got stuck! Try to focus on a specific programming problem. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a threshold, the cloudy (grey) area is removed:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("img.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", thresh)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That was the first solution I came up with. However, it causes problems on certain areas like hair. I am looking for "convert all cloudy areas to black"-like solution.